# Why is std::initializer_list conversion not preferred?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, overload-resolution

Consider this snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void f(std::vector<int>){std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';}
void f(int x){std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';}

int main() 
{
    f({42});
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39073c5354935719)

If you run it, you can see that the `f(int)` overload was preferred, even though `std::vector` has an [`std::initializer_list` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (see #8).

**Question**: Why is the conversion `{42}` to `int` preferred (instead of conversion to `std::vector`, as `{42}` is an `std::initializer_list`)?

Comment: This is tagged [c++11] but the linked Coliru is compiled with `-std=c++17`. The inconsistency does not feel right although it does not affect the question.

Comment: `{42}` is not a `std::initializer_list`. It is an `int` in braces. It is not an expression and does not have a type.

Comment: @NickyC modified

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In overload resolution, when considers [implicit conversion sequence in list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Implicit_conversion_sequence_in_list-initialization),

(emphasis mine)

> Otherwise, if the parameter type is not a class and the initializer
>   list **has one element**, the implicit conversion sequence is the one
>   required to convert the element to the parameter type

Given `f({42});`, for `f(int)`, the implicit conversion sequence is the one to convert the element (i.e. `42`) to `int`, which is an exact match; for `f(std::vector<int>)`, user-defined conversion (converting `std::initializer_list<int>` to `std::vector<int>`) is required then it's a worse match.

PS: if the braced-initializer contains more than one element such as `{42, 42}`, `f(std::vector<int>)` will be selected.